# I want to implement a 2-active crossover circuit with LM833 and amplify it using LM386 and now the problem is I couldn't understand the circuit

Tags: audio, speakers, active-filter, inverting-amplifier, high-pass-filter

I can understand up to certain level that we used a buffer, low pass filter but I can not connect with circuit and coming to components we used 120 Ω, 6.8 nF for active crossover with power supply + 15 & -15. We combined the output of both high and low filter output and amplified it by using LM386 with gain 20 and which can be controlled by using potentiometer. Now if any one can explain each IC it would be helpful.

[image: CIRCUIT WHICH I MODIFIED]

Comment: LM386 needs a big capacitor between output and speaker.

Comment: Three questions: 1. Does the circuit actually work? 2. Is this school work? 3. Do you have specific questions about the circuit sections? "i couldn't understand" does not give us any information about what you want to know. Why don't you tell us your understanding of each circuit section, and we will give you guidance.

Answer (score 1):

First thoughts:

1. There are four connection does that are not associated with components or net connections.  These could indicate incorrect connections.
2. The circuit id DC coupled from the signal input to the LM386 input.  This means that any DC offset voltage errors, a small DC component of the input signal, or something else can be amplified by the entire circuit.
3. It looks like R5, R9, and everything associated with U2:A do not do anything.  R5 and R9 are connected between two virtual grounds, and U2:A does nothing but drive a scope channel.
4. There is nothing to prevent a DC charge accumulating in the C6 integrator capacitor.  This will eventually cause the U3:A output to saturate.

In Fact . . .

I don't think the circuit does anything other than invert the input signal.  U3:B is a unity-gain inverter, and it drives the output amplifier directly.  The chip's output impedance is so low that any filtered signal from R7 will be swamped.

Start with a block diagram of the circuit blocks you think you need, and how the signals are interconnected.  Once we have a good plan for the overall circuit, we can fill in the blocks with schematics and parts.